# Opening Google Chrome on multiple users

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to open Google Chrome with a specific url on all of your chrome users/profiles?

I already tried:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="<profile_1>" "<url>"
```

And it works but when I execute it again for a different profile Google Chrome doesn't make a new instance of its browser for that user.